# How can I get the createMultiMaterialObject in THREE.js to work properly in r62?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I simply cannot make createMultiMaterialObject to work like I assume it's intended to work.
I want a wireframe material being displayed on top of a solid material. All the multimaterial does is display the first material defined in the array.

Heres the code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(  this.model.density.width, this.model.density.height, this.model.density.x, this.model.density.y);
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xd02000, transparent: true } )
var blackLines = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, transparent:true, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 1 } );
var materials = [mat1, blackLines ];

this.plane = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials );
```

In the image below, the red 'ground' is the mesh that is supposed to have the multimaterial, although only one will ever show up (in this case a red MeshBasicMaterial).

[image: foo]

Comment: Default opacity is 1. `var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xd02000, transparent: true, opacity : 0.5 } )`

Comment: Can you provide a simple live example (jsfiddle) to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/YXWNVW) which shows an example how to do this:

Below is the same code

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, cube;

var ww = window.innerWidth,
  wh = window.innerHeight;

function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.getElementById('scene')
  });
  renderer.setSize(ww, wh);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, ww / wh, 0.1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
  scene.add(camera);

  //Generate cube on the scene
  createCube();
}


var createCube = function() {

  //Simple box geometry
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(150, 150, 150);

  //Create a basic material with green color
  var basicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  });

  //Create a material just for the wireframe
  var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    wireframe: true
  });

  //createMultiMaterialObject will create a Mesh for each material in the array
  //We will get 2 cubes in a 3D object
  //You can check with the console that the scene has 2 children, the camera and a 3D object
  //The 3D object contains 2 Mesh with respective material (color for the 1st and wireframe for the 2nd)
  cube = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, [basicMaterial, wireframeMaterial]);

  //Add my cube on the scene
  if (scene) {
    scene.add(cube);
  }

  //Launch animation of the scene
  render();
};

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  if (cube) {
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  }


  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

init();
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```